# The type 'NavigationWindow' does not support direct content

Tags: .net, wpf, navigation, window, navigationwindow

I am trying to use NavigationWindow class instead of Window to allow navigation between windows in WPF application. But when adding content to the NavigationWindow in XAML, I am getting an error:
"The type 'NavigationWindow' does not support direct content". How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: How does your xaml look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add any content to a NavigationWindow.
It is just a "Window" where the Page is going to run, so you have to tell the NavigationWindow wich Page it is going to initial run, you do that by using "Source"
Like this:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="Tes.TesWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300" Source="Window1.xaml">
</NavigationWindow>
```

See a tutorial here:
http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=4190